# Javascript mobile redirect issue

Tags: javascript, redirect

Hi this has doing my head in for an hour or so now, I want to redirect my mobile traffic but depending on the GEO to different locations, I have got the redirect script working fine using switch, case but when I add it within an if statement  if (screen.width <= 699) for mobile devices its not working and I dont know why. this is what i have

```
 <script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
 <script language="JavaScript">
   var country = geoip_country_code();
   if (screen.width <= 699) {   
   switch (country)
   {
   case (country = "ES"):
     window.location = "http://url1.com";
   break;
   case (country = "US"):
     window.location = "http://url1.com";
   break;

   default:
     window.location = "http://url2.com";
   break;
  }
 }
```

Just having it like this work fine...

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
var country = geoip_country_code();
switch (country)
{
case (country = "ES"):
  window.location = "http://url1.com";
break;
case (country = "US"):
  window.location = "http://url1.com";
break;

default:
  window.location = "http://url2.com";
break;
}
```

thanks in advance to anyone who can help me with this I really appreciate it!

Comment: could not be the solution but you don't need a 'break' after the default statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the following in your html's header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

So your mobile devices don't resize to "desktop" emulation

Comment: are you saying that the code is correct then? all I need to do is add this meta data

Comment: Haven't tested it on my mobile, but on a dry run i can tell you most mobile UAs resize the "screen.width" in order to be compatible with desktop sites.

Comment: ok got ya... but still doesnt seem to work I also tried if (window.width < 700)   and still nothing so the code looks fine to you?

Comment: What mobile devices are you testing? EDIT: it's working for me on android.

Comment: yeah android also, I will retry anf test in the morning, but thanks for your help mate... really appreciate it!